# openURL not working?

Tags: iphone, ios5, mp3, jailbreak, openurl

I have my apache2 server running on my macbook pro and I have an ssh session into my iphone which runs on iOS 5.0.1. I have a folder "files" in my webroot which has a few mp3 files. When I try accessing those files using the browser in my iPhone, the media files are played and I can see the corresponding logs in /private/var/log/apache2/access_log.

However, when I try opening the files from the iPhone terminal(via the ssh session) by using the command line utility "openURL", I dont see any logs at my server side which leads me to believe that the files are not opened at all.

Am I doing something wrong? An example of what I tried looks like :-

> $ openURL http://192.168.71.71/files/1.mp3

Comment: I dont seem to have a "open" binary in my iPhone, its "openURL". could you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

openURL is a jailbreak binary, and it's not working for me either, since I upgraded to IOS 4.3.3.

You can try reinstalling the latest version, it appears to be called "openurl" no uppercase, it may work on iOS 5, although I'm skeptical.   It should be fairly simple to write one that works, I'm going to give it a go this week.